# Showing that the global behaviour of a linear map $T:\mathrm{R}^n \to \mathrm{R}^m$ is determined by the behavior on the open ball $\mathcal{B}(0, r)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The question from my source is from word to word: "*Let $T: \mathrm{R}^n \to \mathrm{R}^m$ be a linear mapping. Show that for every $r > 0$, the behavior of $T$ on $\mathcal{B}(0, r)$ determines the behavior of $T$ everywhere.*" What I'm not really understanding is that what is the desired result regarding the global behavior of $T$? Namely, as $T$ is linear, it belongs to $\mathcal{O}(h)$, so that $\exists c > 0.\exists \delta_c > 0: |h| < \delta \implies |T(h)| < c|h|$. Thus if we define $\delta = \min\{\delta_r, r\}$, then for $x \in \mathcal{B}(0, \delta) \subseteq \mathcal{B}(0, r)$ it holds true that $|x| = |x - 0| < \delta \implies |T(x)| < \delta|x| \leq r|x|$. But what is the deeper truth behind all this? What is the desired characterization of the global behavior of $T$?

Comment: It means that the values of $T$ everywhere are known provided that you know its values on an open ball. This is because a linear map is homogeneous: if $x\neq 0$, then $T(x) = \frac{2\|x\|}{r}T\left(\frac{rx}{2\|x\|}\right)$ and $\frac{rx}{2\|x\|}\in B(0,r)$.

Comment: The way you put it, the source is not very clear. However, they surely mean what Didier said. Finally, I don't know what you mean by $\mathcal O(h)$, but I do not plan to discover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this statement it's enough to assume that $T$ respects scalar multiplication: $T(\lambda x)=\lambda\,T(x)$ for all $\lambda\in\Bbb R$, which is one of the conditions of being *linear*.

Indeed, if we know all values $T(x)$ for $x\in B(0,r)$ for some $r>0$, then for any $y$ with $\|y\|\ge r$, we must have
$$T(y)=\frac{2\|y\|}r\,T\left(\frac r{2\|y\|}\,y\right)$$
where $\frac r{2\|y\|}\,y$ has norm $\frac r2$, so it's in $B(0,r)$.